# Is the node.js 'non blocking' future relevant for regular websites?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, node.js

PHP has only one thread so that means it can perform 1 command at a time, while node.js has the 'non blocking' future (the event loop) so it can perform asynchronous functions.

I don't see how this is useful. For example - if a user performs a form registration with a `POST` request and we need to insert that data to the database, both Node and PHP need to complete the operation and only then return the response to the user.

If we want to get data from the server, both Node and PHP will query data from the database, wait until the data retrieval is finished and then return the answer to the user. That means the client needs to wait anyway.

So of what benefit is the "non blocking" future?

Comment: Unless i'm mistaken (I'm not a php developer), php uses one thread *per request*, where as node.js would use one thread for all requests, ignoring the fact that some node actions do spawn additional threads for other things such as interacting with the file system for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With node, a single thread deals with ALL requests to the application, not just one request. This is where the event loop and asynchronous logic comes into play. Without it, node.js would only be able to process one request at a time. With it, node.js can accept a request, send a request to the database for data, and then while waiting for the data to get back, accept another request and process it too.

Answer (score 1):

Node asynchronous comes handy when you want to perform couple of requests for user at a time / use websockets